# import host groups in Zabbix

Tags: import, zabbix

hi created several scripts for importing nodes into zabbix, this all works as it should except when in my import file is a node with a hostgoup name that doesn't match any groups in Zabbix

In an ideal world I would like to create the hostgoup when it doesn't exist.

I tried to add the host group bit to the xml file but that's obviously not the right way

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<zabbix_export> 
<version>6.2</version> 
<date>2022-12-26T17:16:35Z</date> 
<hostgroups>
<hostgroup>
<name>TESTERS</name>
</hostgroup>
</hostgroups>
<hosts> 
<host>
</host>
</hosts> 
</zabbix_export>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried exporting an host from Zabbix 5, and importing to a different Zabbix 5, and it works. It created the missing host groups.

In the import procedure, be sure to select "Create new groups".

The XML generated by Zabbix was:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zabbix_export>
    <version>5.0</version>
    <date>2023-01-05T08:56:23Z</date>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>customer: foo</name>
        </group>
        <group>
            <name>platform: WINDOWS</name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <hosts>
        <host>
            <host>myserver</host>
            <name>myserver - test</name>
            <proxy>
                <name>myproxy</name>
            </proxy>
            <templates>
                <template>
                    <name>Template VM VMware</name>
                </template>
            </templates>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>customer: foo</name>
                </group>
...
```

[image: zabbix import procedure]